# Interpolating two melodies into a single melody

Tags: melody, algorithmic-composition

I have been experimenting with an algorithmic/mathematical approach to combine two melodies into a single, new melody and want to ask if there are other approaches to this problem.

[Example combination of two known melodies](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14RQvL2Ukr_lrwbeEfHpg7pzFkF8bDCw7/view)

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/githubuser1983/twelfth_root_of_two), and the method is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115897/twelfth-root-of-two)

Edit:
I could interpolate two simple melodies to generate this piece: [audio](https://musescore1983.bandcamp.com/track/interpolation), [score](https://musescore.com/user/37663311/scores/6738622)

Comment: In the other post you are asking an awkward question: "My mathematical question is, if there is a musically better way to combine these melody-matrices". That's really confusing, and actually pointless in my opinion. What you're asking in "musical terms" seems mostly about *aesthetics* and: 1. that's clearly not something relateable in mathematical functions; 2. aesthetics is a very broad and highly subjective aspect, and in most cases simple algorithms (no matter how the involved math is complex) are not able to be involved in such aspects (machine learning is usually a preferred path).

Comment: @musicamante: you are wrong with that. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two The perceived aesthetics is because of "simple" rational numbers which are captured by the formula described in the other post.

Comment: And where's the relation to music aesthetics in that? I'm not talking about the relation between intervals, that's a completely different subject.

Comment: Difficult to describe. It is based on measuring simple rational numbers and converting them to vectors. Then doing matrix singular value decomposition.

Comment: Mine was a rhetorical question... The 12th root has nothing to do with the aesthetic of the composition, and is only related in musical aspects for the basic frequency relations. It has absolutely nothing to do with making a composition "beautiful" or "terrible" or "better" or "worse", nor the aesthetics related to the composition practices in harmony (other than the abovementioned relations) nor form.

Comment: Have you compared it to the algorithm "give both melodies to a musician and ask him/her to improvise based on them" ?

Comment: How do you interpolate between two sentences, say "John likes dogs" and "What did we have for dinner yesterday?" Any number of ways. For example, letter by letter. Swap letters starting from the start. Or remove letters until empty, then start adding letters from the target sentence. Do the in-between forms make sense? Do they have to? I don't know. Interesting proposal anyway.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica: Thanks for your comment. By your argument, there is no "right" or "wrong" in combining two melodies. So I guess I will stick with the method.

Comment: A melody carries bits about all dimensions of music, including harmony and rhythm. If melody A outlines some harmonic changes - like "chord changes", and melody B outlines different changes, what should an interpolated melody do? How about rhythm then - if melody A carries a rhythm that naturally conveys a 3/4 metric feel, but melody B is more like in 7/8, what should an interpolated melody feel like rhythmically? If melody A _modulates_, but melody B does not, how to interpolate? How to interpolate between different structures and behaviors? 50% elevator, 50% cucumber? Doesn't work as either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking into two things:

In "traditional", common practice music there is something called *compound melody* which is a single melodic line, but because the pitches get grouped into high/low regions, or through other devices, the single line seems to be a counterpoint of two separate lines. In some ways this is just a "trick." If you take two basic lines in counterpoint - for example, something in simple quarter notes - all you need to do is displace the notes of each line with quarter rests so the notes alternate back and forth between the two. It's a way to get a melodic instrument like a flute to sound like it's playing harmony.

In modern *serial music* you can have a series of pitches - a melody - and the series, sometimes called a *row*, can be permuted in various ways including breaking it up into smaller segments or recombining with itself in various counterpoints. This style is usually atonal. It's more math-ish treating all permutations are about equally viable.

Either of these could be described as some kind of multiple lines combined into, or derived from, a single line.

Oh, there's one other, really it technically fits into the serial stuff, but historically it's part of counterpoint and canon technique. The *cancrizan*, or crab canon. It's one melody played in counterpoint to itself played in retrograde, backwards. Since it's a separate term, I thought I should mention it.